# Complexity of computing zk-SNARK Proofs

Tags: elliptic-curves, homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, blind-signature

Disclaimer: I have no background in cryptography, and everything I'm asking about is what I've learnt from last couple of days of frantic reading on this topic. Any help is much appreciated.

Q: What does the computational complexity of generating a zkSNARK proof and verifying it scale with?

Specifically, how many bilinear pairings, curve point additions and scalar multiplications are involved in generating and verifying a proof? Are these linear in the number of constraints in the system?

[Here](https://medium.com/@imolfar/why-and-how-zk-snark-works-8-zero-knowledge-computation-f120339c2c55), I can see that there each verification requires the verifier to compute $11$ curve pairings, $3*m$ scalar multiplications, and $3(m+1)$ curve point additions. First of all, is my understanding correct? Second, what is $m$? Is that the number of constraints? Third, how can I similarly calculate the number of pairings, additions and multiplications that the prover has to compute if I know the number of constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its depend on the protocol used. The last and more efficient is [Groth16](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf) that use only 3 curve points in its proofs. You can see the size of the keys and the  the proofs in the table 2 of Groth's paper. The computation complexity of the pairing depends of whats curve is used. In general ZoKrates/Ethereum and ZCash use the bn256 curve paramters and the pairing algorithm used in their package (at least in the [golang's one](https://github.com/clearmatics/bn256/blob/master/optate.go#L120)) is the [algorithm 1](https://cryptojedi.org/papers/dclxvi-20100714.pdf) of the miller ate pairings.

You see zk-SNARK is an amalgamation of various works and its complexity depends on the implementation that is evolving day to day.

Comment: Could you clarify what the size of the instance $l$ represents when it is stated (E.g. in Table 1 [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/099.pdf)) that the Verifier computation cost in Groth16 is $3$ Pairings + $l$ Exponentations? Is $l$ supposed to be the number of public inputs provided to the snarkVerifier call?

Comment: In the Groth16 verification protcol you have to construct a sigma element by multiplying the $vk_x$ element of the verifier key with the public inputs and then verify the pairing equation of the protocol. So yeah, I think $l$-size statement means $l$ public inputs.

Comment: you can see this in the Vfy algorithm detailed in [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf) in section 3.1